# What does PDO's `rowCount()` return if the MySQL query fails?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I'm writing some code using PDO with MySQL, and need to be **very sure** whether or not an `UPDATE` succeeded.

I expect to update 1 row, and I'm using PDO's `rowCount()` method to check for a return value of 1. If either 1 or 0 rows were affected ("updated" or "didn't update"), I know what to do.

Can this go wrong in any way? For example, **what does it return if the query fails to execute?** What if the database is somehow corrupted or fell over?

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to check the return value of the `execute()` and see if the query failed that way?

Answer (score 0):

If the query fails execute will return false. If it succeed than returned value will be affected row count. It can be >=0. Don't use rowCount for checking if update did occured or no because it should always return one row, unless query failed (due to error)

`sqrt(-1) loves php`

Comment: "it should always return one row, unless query failed" In my case, or always? `UPDATE ... WHERE` could update N rows, so `rowCount` should return N, right?

Comment: In case of UPDATE - always. false would be if you will have eh. syntax error or reference to not existing tables etc.
And as for your comment, not exactly. If eg you will update row with the same data (so row will actually not be modified), affected row count will be 0. But in general yes, it will return count of modified rows. I think that there should be second row that should point how many rows was matched by `where` clause - if mysql workbench knows that, it means that DBMS must provide such information on response, but i never used it.

Answer (score -1):

In a properly written application it just never gets executed - an exception is fired and handler just kills the whole script.